# Deployment individual components in unified interface Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-uci, powerapps-modeldriven

All the views in the unified interface are not showing up until we go and check those views in the app designer to show up. We did this in dev and we would like to export and import these changes to prod. But I do not want to do it as whole app as all the changes in the app gets pushed out. Is there any way that I can only do it for specific entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual app is the single logical container of all the assets/artifacts to be configured granularly & deployed. Other than that we have individual sitemap for that app.

If you don’t want to wait till the current development changes (app along with newly configured assets) to be pushed from Dev to other environments, then you have two choices:

1. Do the changes manually in other environments
2. Take the Dev app backup, restore the app from Prod to Dev, add the required assets & deploy as a hot fix in other regions. Then restore the backup App solution in Dev again